# Flutter. Show last 5 elements listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can show last 5 elements in widget with listview.builder?
Thanks!

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  // shrinkWrap: true,
                  // reverse: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length ,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    // controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
                    if (snapshot.data![index].operatorName == 'barz1' ||
                        snapshot.data![index].operatorName == 'barz2') {
                      return Container(
```

Comment: what do you mean by last 5 elements

Comment: I fetch data with 50 elements, I want show last 5

Comment: can you include the code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length ,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if(index > snapshot.data!.length - 5){ /// <--- add this condition
           if (snapshot.data![index].operatorName == 'barz1' ||
            snapshot.data![index].operatorName == 'barz2') {
              return Container(...);
           }
        }
      }
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `reverse` property true in `Listview.builder` and set `itemcount` to 5 to get last 5 elements in widget with `ListView.Builder`.

```js
ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
```

Comment: if you're fetching from firebase then You can add orderBy() to descend sorting the message. for example firestore.collection('messages').orderBy("created_at", descending: true).snapshots().

Comment: Working, but show not last elements

Comment: Yes, I did this

Comment: Did you tried to **descending** property to false?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final originalList=snapshot.data;
          final newList=originalList.sublist(originalList.length-5, originalList.length);
            return ListView.builder(
              controller: controller,
              // shrinkWrap: true,
              // reverse: true,
              itemCount: newList.length ,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                // controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
                if (newList[index].operatorName == 'barz1' ||
                    newList[index].operatorName == 'barz2') {
                  return Container(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create sublist from original data.

```dart
class Fas4 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Fas4({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
        future: Future.value(List.generate(333, (index) => index)),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //handle other state like error...
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data ?? [];

            List<int> subList =
                data.length <= 5 ? data : data.sublist(data.length - 6);

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: subList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("${subList[index]}"),
            );
          }
          return Text("Loading");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```